# How to count number of attributes and then link back to road network - pgrouting

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, count, array

I have created generated a many-to-many shortest distance route using *pgRouting*. The output table displays the typical *pgRouting* outputs (`seq, path_seq, edge, node, cost` etc.) as well as the road network attributes (`gid, road number, road name, function, class` etc.).

If I export this table into Excel, I can create a pivot table to view the number of edges traversed for each road name as shown below

[image]

I think I can use this script to view number of edges traversed by road name. However, how would I join this back onto the road network, i.e. join onto fixed_Roads where fixed_road.gid = edges?

```
SELECT name1,
       count(edge)
FROM   array_trips
GROUP BY
       name1
;
```

Output example:

```
"Aberdeen Road" "748"
"Addison Road"  "79"
"Aiken Street"  "53"
"Albert Crescent"   "901"
"Albert Parade" "2"
"Albert Road"   "2911"
```

Comment: You can only ever meaningfully aggregate `gid`s per `name1` (into an array, or concatenated string), as you are effectively counting them into groups (per `name1`); is that the desired output?

Comment: Yes, so I am looking at traffic counts which is equivalent to count(edges)/ count(gid). These need to be joined back onto the road network in one query

Comment: Oh wait, you just want the same behavior as with Excel here? Note that, if I'm not mistaken, both counts should always be equal.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Since I am not entirely sure what your intentions are with respect to aggregation, here just a generic example; I strongly recommend to read the PG docs and some tutorials on basic SQL logic *if* the mechanics of relational `JOIN`s is the actual question here.

A `GROUP BY` statement is applied on the *full (virtual) set of records and columns* that are available *after* the complete list of `FROM` expressions are considered, including table `JOIN`s and correlated sub-queries.

In your case, if your intention is to being able to aggregate column values from `fixed_Roads`, all you have to do is adding a `JOIN` to it (just like you describe), and apply the grouping (with some random aggregations jsut for demonstration purposes):

```
SELECT fr.name1,
       COUNT(at.edge) AS full_count,
       COUNT(DISTINCT at.edge) AS unique_count,
       ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT fr.gid) AS unique_gids,
       ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT fr.class) AS unique_classes,
       SUM(ST_Length(fr.geom::GEOGRAPHY)) AS total_length_traversed_in_meter
FROM   array_trips AS at
JOIN   "fixed_Roads" AS fr
  ON   fr.gid = at.edge
GROUP BY
       fr.name1
;
```

---

*This assumes all network meta info is pulled from `"fixed_Roads"`, while your question reads as if those values are present in `array_trips` already; please clarify what columns are found where, and what values you need to aggregate if this doesn't help.*